# AC Circuits: Determine the RMS current in the Inductor in the circuit diagram attached below. (Voltage is 40V, RMS)

Tags: current, ac, inductor, rms

Here is the image of the circuit diagram. I wanted to know the method to evaluate the RMS current in the inductor branch. I would prefer to use complex analysis!
[image: Here is the circuit diagram]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the mesh-current method. You could use source substitution to convert between current and voltage sources, combining impedances along the way. You could use the node voltage method but it wouldn't be my first choice. You could combine the impedances until you have a single impedance across the source, figure out the current through that impedance, then work back through your transformations to find the desired current. Any technique that works for dc analysis will work for steady-state ac analysis if you work with the complex impedances.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented and answered, working with steady state AC problems is very similiar to working through a DC analysis. The same types of methods can be applied with the only addition burden of complex numbers. Take for example the following  circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzrtLB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we wanted to find the current flowing thru the capacitor, we would would calculate:
$$ I = \frac{V1}{Z1 + Z2} $$

Now, if I gave the following information:

1. \$ V1 = 30 \$
2. \$ Z1 = 100 \$
3. \$ Z2 = -j 10 \$

The current due to these impedances would be 
$$ I = \frac{ 30}{100 -j10} = .297 + j.0297 $$

To the specifics of your problem, try replacing the capacitor and inductor with resistors and solving for the current thru the 5 \$ \Omega \$ resistor using any method you are comfortable with. The same process will work using the complex values.